# Share internet connection from computer without NAT

Tags: wireless, networking, network-manager, nat

Is there a way to use my laptop with a wifi card and provide network access to my laptop without NAT? I currently set up network manager to share the internet connection and I can browse the internet and ping machines in the 192.168.1.xxx network just fine, but none of those computers can reach my desktop behind my laptop. My desktop's ip is 10.42.0.92 while my laptop's ip over ethernet is 10.42.0.1. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to share an Internet connection, a proxy server, and NAT.  NAT provides automatic translation of incoming and outgoing data, which makes it easy to deal with the clients to make them work with it

NAT gives you clear Internet access to all computers in local network and works great with almost any protocol. Using NAT, there's no need to modify settings on each computer.

The Proxy Server acts as a client computer at the remote host. Plus it works with only a few protocols that support it.  Proxy has an advantage, since it provides advanced features such as authentication and user based access control.